# IIS 8.5 on Server 2012, passwords with special characters, such as an asterisk (*)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a custom IIS application that uses Windows Authentication and runs fine on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

After migrating the code to Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5, our custom IIS application no longer successfully authenticates users who have special characters like asterisk (*) or exclamations (!) in their passwords.

Other users, with no special characters, authenticate fine.

I assume this is some new, additional layer of protection or filtering that Server 2012 R2 or IIS 8.5 has.

Is there any way to make our Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 system work like our Server 2008 R2/ IIS 7 system, with passwords that contain special characters?

Comment: IIS delegates the actual authentication (Windows authentication) to Windows API and directory services. Thus, you need to ask your domain administrators to assist. There is nothing you can do on your side.

Comment: The only server that changed is the IIS host. The Domain Controller works fine with Server 2008 and IIS 7.5 and complex passwords.

Comment: Again, without the domain administrators' help you won't know what's up. It is not surprising to see AD works for some machines, but fails for others. Whatever configuration is incorrect, you won't find it on IIS side.